# In typescript, how to export the type of a private class without exporting class itself

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a module in which public method of a public class creates and returns a new instance of a private class. The requirement is that `MyClassPrivateHelper` must only be instantiated by `MyClass`.

```
class MyClassPrivateHelper {
    constructor(private cls: MyClass) {
    }

    public someHelperMethod(arg): void {
        this.cls.someMethod();
    }
}
export class MyClass {
    public createHelper(): MyClassPrivateHelper {  // error here
        return new MyClassPrivateHelper(this);
    }

    public someMethod(): void {
        /**/
    }
}
```

With this arrangement TypeScript reports error:

`[ts] Return type of public method from exported class has or is using private name 'MyClassPrivateHelper'.`

My goal is to export just the "type" of the private class without letting an module consuming code be able instantiate it directly. e.g.

```
const mycls = new module.MyClass();

// should be allowed
const helper: MyClassPrivateHelper = mycls.createHelper();

// should not be allowed
const helper = new module.MyClassPrivateHelper();
```

I have tried using `typeof` like so without success.

```
export type Helper = typeof MyClassPrivateHelper
```

Maybe I am not understanding how "typeof" works. My questions are:

- Why export of type using `typeof` not working?
- How do I export type without exposing the private class outside module?

Comment: What exactly is MyClassPrivateHelper type? MyClassPrivateHelper has no public members in the code above.

Comment: Create an interface for `MyClassPrivateHelper`. export and use that instead.

Comment: I cannot replicate the error from your example. Are you using the latest version of TypeScript?

Comment: @Behrooz It happens if you enable `declaration` emitting

Comment: @estus I updated the code to add a public method to show usage. @Behrooz I am using TS version 2.7.2. As Titian said, I have `"declaration": true` in my `tsconfig`.

Comment: Yes, you have not understood how _typeof_ works. It returns a string indicating the type and that is not what you want here. Use an interface, see my answer below.

Answer (score 21):

> Why export of type using typeof not working?
>
> ```
> export type MyInterface = typeof MyClassPrivateHelper
> ```

In this example `MyInterface` is the type of the constructor function but you'd like to export the type of the instances this constructor can produce.

> How do I export type without exposing the private class outside module?

Like this:

```
export type MyInterface = InstanceType<typeof MyClassPrivateHelper>
```

`InstanceType` is described briefly here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html.

Alternatively, I found that the following also works:

```
type Interface<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }
export interface MyInterface extends Interface<MyClassPrivateHelper> {}
```

The `Interface` type basically copies all public properties from `T`, which we then use to declare a new interface.

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/471#issuecomment-381842426 for more details.

Answer (score 6):

You should create an interface and export that:

```
export interface IMyHelper {
   someHelperMethod(arg): void;
}
```

and then let the Helper implement that:

```
class MyClassPrivateHelper implements IMyHelper {
    constructor(private cls: MyClass) {
    }

    public someHelperMethod(arg): void {
        this.cls.someMethod();
    }
}
```

The public class will return the interface

```
export class MyClass {
    public createHelper(): IMyHelper { 
        return new MyClassPrivateHelper(this);
    }

    public someMethod(): void {
        /**/
    }
}
```

From the outside the helper is again referenced by its interface:

```
const helper: IMyHelper = mycls.createHelper();
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this is the following:

```js
class MyClassPrivateHelper {
    constructor(private cls: any) {
    }
    public someHelperMethod(arg: any): void {
        this.cls.someMethod();
    }
}

export type Helper = MyClassPrivateHelper;
```

Calling `export type Helper = InstanceType<typeof MyClassPrivateHelper>` is redundant.